# Redirect failed in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I am trying to get the fc_id of the immunization then past it in profiling but the problem is the redirect() doesn't work. I successfully transfer my fc_id but the problem is i can't go to profiling view when i click the button.

[Here some photo to understand my question clearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUzo3.jpg)

So here's my code.

View:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#view_profile", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var view_id = $(this).attr("value");

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>immunization/view_profile",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      view_id: view_id
    }
  });

});
```

```html
 <a href="#" value="${row.fc_id}" id="view_profile" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View Profile</a>
```

Immunization Controller:

```html
    public function view_profile(){
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session'); 

        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            $view_id = $this->input->post('view_id');

            $this->session->set_tempdata('view_id', $view_id); 
            redirect('profiling/index');
    }
}
```

Profiling Controller:

```html
public function index(){
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session'); 
        $this->load->view('profiling');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to redirect in an ajax request and thats not gonna work. Just post back some message if everything is ok and in ajax succes check that message and redirect from there with `location.href = yoururl` like:

In your php:

```
$this->session->set_tempdata('view_id', $view_id); 
echo json_encode('msg' => 'ok');
```

js:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>immunization/view_profile",
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    view_id: view_id
  }
  success: function(resp){
    if (resp.msg == 'ok') location.href = 'profiling/index';
  }
```

});

Comment: It's work. Though i modified some of your answers.

Here is my working code.

$this->session->set_tempdata('view_id', $view_id); 
$data = array('msg' => 'ok');
echo json_encode($data);

Then in my script:

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>immunization/view_profile",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      view_id: view_id
    },
    success: function(resp){
    if (resp.msg == 'ok') location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>profiling/index';
  }
  });

});

Thank you so much for responding to my question.